# .Xap download if there is any change in version of .xap file

Tags: silverlight

I am using MEF in Silverlight for dynamic download .xap file. I want to download .xap file only one time and then I want to download .xap file only when if there is any change in version of .xap file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is normal behaviour. The .xap file will only be downloaded if:

1. There is a change in the .xap file at the server.
2. The user clears their cache and so no longer has the file on their machine any more.

We have seen cases where the .xap file *isn't* downloaded when there has been a change.

What are you seeing that makes you think the .xap file is being downloaded each time?

The last accessed time in your cache merely shows the time the application was last *run*, not the time the .xap file was last downloaded.

Comment: I am using package catalog to download .xap file on button click event. My question is that is it every time download .xap file when i click on button or only first time download and after that uses from cache.